# How do I stop heroku from restarting a 3rd party script? (Vanilla Forums)

Tags: php, git, deployment, heroku

(Sorry, newbie here)
So I managed to push my local php web app to their servers, using the tutorial I've found on the net on how to push php projects. It worked perfectly fine.

Now, when I load my site. The script installation appears (Vanilla Forums) and so I did the proper installation and used the CLEARDB add-on to provide MYSQL database for the site.

The forum is only part of my whole website, the problem is.. every time I change something on my website, git commit it and pushing to heroku.. The app installation of vanilla forums reappears.

How could I stop git or heroku from changing the forum part to it's last commited state?
(Note that I have successfully installed the forum software but when I commit and push because of a small update to other part of my site, the forum software reinstall again)

For better understanding: 
My site url: http://codeknack.herokuapp.com
The forum url: http://codeknack.herokuapp.com/forum

This is the structure of my whole website:
index.php

challenges/

meetups/

tutorials/

community/

forum/

where in the forum folder lies the vanilla forum php script and when I edit just part of the index.php of my website, vanilla forum shows the installation screen again.

(If I am too vague, please tell me what part you are confused at)

This will really help a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why they invented the **[`.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)** file. You can specify files, directories, and wildcards to be ignored by git.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that already.. But it seems that it cannot ignore an already tracked folder.. Or when I reset it using the git rm --cached.. It just deletes the folder on heroku's server and the forum is gone...